# Access list data as a group

Tags: list, ms-access, grouping

We have a company program designed to help us get control over data. It has feature to group all the application of one Client. If I want to take a look at them I click on the Client and I see a list of all applications made for him. Take a look at the picture below:

[image: ![enter image description here]

I was wondering if Microsoft Access can do the same? If yes where should I start looking?

I did some internet search and no solution found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is built in, and it is called [Subdatasheet](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Add-a-subdatasheet-900d1d30-5ea2-4e47-80a7-ddcb87a53d14). You have relationships properly set between Clients and Order, for instance, when you open the Clients table you will see such small "+" allowing to view the Orders of the current client. You may have to set the `Subdatasheet Name` property of table Clients to "Orders" in this case.

If you want to work with forms, you can build a continuous from for Clients, then one for Orders, then insert the Orders subform in the Footer of the Clients form. Access might tell you you can't do this, just ignore, it works.

Comment: No chances to make it in Form? To tell the truth Subdatasheet looks pretty awful for end-user.

Comment: Found some youtube tutorial showing what you told: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BtGM9h3l-3s I will try it and write back about results.

Comment: Thanks! This is something similar to what I wanted to achieve. Still basing on your idea and template from youtube.

Answer (score 0):

In Access that would simply be a continuous form with a filter. Typically opened from a list of clients, setting a filter for the applications of the selected client.

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question.

Comment: I have updated image maybe this will help to understand it better. It is not about using filters but to visually group items based on some criteria.

Comment: Ah, I see. See iDevlop's answer.